# Why Angular won't start?

Tags: angularjs, initialization

I'm just doing some simple practice with angular 1.x, but the browser doesn't render the value and function inside the brackets, what is wrong?

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="LandingApp">

    <form ng-controller="LandingApp">
        <input type="number" ng-model="numeroaltrepagine">{{numeroaltrepagine}}</input>
        <b>TOTALE</b><br/>
        {{totale() | currency}}
    </form>

    <b>TOTALE</b>



</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

**And Here the js**

```
   var LandingApp = angular.module('LandingApp',[]);

LandingApp.controller('numberpages',function($scope){

    $scope.primapagine = 150;
    $scope.altrepagine = 90;
    $scope.numeroaltrepagine = 1;

    $scope.totale = function(){
        return $scope.altrepagine * $scope.numeroaltrepagine;
    }
});
```

Comment: Correct HTML <form ng-controller="numberpages">

Comment: LandingApp.controller('numberpages',function($scope){  Here numberpages is  your controller name so use <form ng-controller="numberpages">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ng-controller should be **`numberpages`** not **`LandingApp`**,

```
<form ng-controller="numberpages">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var LandingApp = angular.module('LandingApp',[]);
LandingApp.controller('numberpages',function($scope){
$scope.primapagine = 150;
$scope.altrepagine = 90;
$scope.numeroaltrepagine = 1;

$scope.totale = function(){
    return $scope.altrepagine * $scope.numeroaltrepagine;
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>   
</head>

<body ng-app="LandingApp">

    <form ng-controller="numberpages">
        <input type="number" ng-model="numeroaltrepagine">{{numeroaltrepagine}}</input>
        <b>TOTALE</b><br/>
        {{totale() | currency}}
    </form>

    <b>TOTALE</b>



</body>

</html>
```